# wps.setup and WpsInfo.PBC are all depracted at API 28 what alternates are there for connecting using WiFi p2p

Tags: android, wifip2p, wps

wifi p2p connections example is given in android official website [link](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct#connect)

in that there is

```
WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
```

but wps.setup and WpsInfo.PBC are all deprecated at API 28 so what alternates could be used for connecting using wifi p2p

Answer (score 0):

It's changed from deprecated to undeprecated at API 29. https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/29/changes/android.net.wifi.WpsInfo